# Help understanding a proof on the characterization of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, projection-matrices

I'm trying to understand the proof for this:

> A linear transformation $P$ on a vector space $V$ into itself is a *projection* if and only if $P^2 = P$. The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a projection
> 2. There exist subspaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $V = X\oplus Y$, and $T(\textbf{v}) = x$, where $\textbf{ v = x+y, x}\in X,\textbf{y}\in Y$ is the unique decomposition of $\bf v$.

I understand why (2) implies (1) - if $\bf v = x+y$, $\bf x = x+0$ are unique decompositions, then $T^2(\textbf{v}) = T(T(\textbf{v})) = T(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x} = T(\textbf{v})$, so $T^2 = T$.

I'm having difficulty with the proof that (1) implies (2). Here is what my book has:

> Define $X = \mathcal{R}(T), y = \mathcal{N}(T).$ From the decomposition
>   $$\textbf{v} = T(\textbf{v}) + \textbf{v} - T(\textbf{v})$$
>   And the fact that $T(\textbf{v}-T(\textbf{v})) = T(\textbf{v}) - T^2(\textbf{v}) = 0$ follows that $V = X+Y$.
>
> Suppose  now that $\textbf{v}\in\mathcal{R}(T)\cap\mathcal{N}(T).$ This implies that there exists $\textbf{w}\in V$ such that $T(\textbf{w})\in\mathcal{N}(T)$, i.e., $T(T(\textbf{w})) = 0$. But $T(T(\textbf{w}))= T^2(\textbf{w}) = T(\textbf{w}) = \textbf{v}$, so $\textbf{v} = 0$ which proves the assertion.

I'm confused starting with the decomposition. I see that $T(\textbf{v})$ is in the range of T, and $\textbf{v}-T(\textbf{v})$ is in the null space. But where does that decomposition come from? Or is it just supposed to be an identity that is used to show that there are components of $\textbf{v}$ in $X$ and $Y$?

And then the last part is used to show that the intersection of $X$ and $Y$ is zero and so the $+$ becomes an $\oplus$?

So I think writing this out helped me understand a bit better, but verification of my thought process would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: When you ask "where does the decomposition come from", are you not sure why it's true? Clearly $v = v + [T(v) - T(v)]$ and it's gotten just by rearranging the terms.  And the decomposition then follows by noting what you've said right after that. And yes, you are correct about that last part.

Comment: Yeah that's why I mentioned that it seemed just like an identity, but I think I was confused before I realized one part was in the range and the other was in the null space. Thanks and sorry for the triviality of this post